# StringTokenizer error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, stringtokenizer

My code :

```
class Customer
{
String name_dob,name,dob,dd,mm,yyyy;
void stringTokenize()
{
    StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(name_dob,",");
    name = st1.nextElement();
    dob = st1.nextElement();
    StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(dob,"/");
    dd = st2.nextElement();
    mm = st2.nextElement();
    yyyy = st2.nextElement();
}
void display()
{
    System.out.println(name + "," + dd + "," + mm + "," + yyyy);
}
}
public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i,n;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of data");
    n = sc.nextInt();
    Customer[] obj = new Customer[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        obj[i] = new Customer();
        System.out.println("Enter the data");
        obj[i].name_dob = sc.nextLine();
        obj[i].stringTokenize();
    }
    System.out.println("After tokenizing........");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("The data is");
        obj[i].display();
    }

}
}
```

Error that I am getting

> Main.java:23: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String
>           name = st1.nextElement();
>
> Main.java:24: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String
>           dob = st1.nextElement();
>
> Main.java:26: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String
>           dd = st2.nextElement();
>
> Main.java:27: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String
>           mm = st2.nextElement();
>
> Main.java:28: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String
>           yyyy = st2.nextElement();

Comment: Note that it says in the Javadoc: "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.". Or alternatively you could use a `java.util.Scanner`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nextToken` instead of `nextElement`.

The documentation of [`nextElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#nextElement--) says:

> Returns the same value as the nextToken method, except that its declared return value is Object rather than String.

Comment: But can you tell me why was it not working previously??

Comment: Because the method is returning a reference to an `Object`, and the compiler doesn't know if it's actually a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `nextToken` instead of `nextObject`.
Or use `nextObject` and convert it to `String` but it seems like an overhead.

Look at the **[Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/StringTokenizer.html)**

> **nextElement()**
>   Returns the same value as the *nextToken* method, except that its declared return value is Object rather than String.